# How to pass parametrs to DIV section

Tags: html, dialog

I want to design the dialog in html5. This dialog should accept the freetext and image as parameters. I tried to open dialog as below.. Now I want to pass the parameters so that I can use that dialog everywhere..

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>

            <head>
                <style>
                    #overlay
                    {
                        visibility: hidden;
                        position: fixed;
                        left: 0;
                        top: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        text-align: center;
                        z-index: 200;
                        background-image: url(maskBG.png);
                    }

                        #overlay div
                        {
                            width: 300px;
                            margin: 100px auto;
                            background-color: #fff;
                            border: 1px solid #400;
                            padding: 15px;
                            text-align: center;
                        }

                    .close
                    {
                        text-decoration: underline;
                    }
                </style>

                <script>
                    function overlay() {

                        var el = document.getElementById("overlay");
                        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";

                    }

                    function overlayTest(arg) {

                        //alert(arg);
                        var el = document.getElementById("overlay").click(moveImages('Testing123'));
                        //alert(arg);
                        // el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";

                    }

                    function close() {
                        document.getElementById("overlay").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    }

                    function moveImages(arg) {
                        alert('in Move Images');
                    }


                </script>

            </head>

            <body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="blue" vlink="purple" alink="red">

                <p align="center">

                    <button type="button" onclick="overlay()" id="btnEffluentTreatment">EFFLUENT TREATMENT</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="overlayTest('My MyTesting')" id="btnTry">Try1</button>

                </p>

                <div id="overlay" >
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            <img src="010.png" />
                            Content/Images whatever we want the user to see goes here.

                        </p>
                        <button type="button" onclick="overlay()" id="btnEffluentTreatment">Close</button>



                    </div>
                </div>

            </body>

            </html>
```

Comment: What I will do for this case, I will create one inner html tag may be div tag and set to display:none. When user click one parent I will read child and append to overlay div..

Comment: Yes that what I am doing now... but how the issue is how to pass the message to be display to that DIV ?